# Pandas: repeating rows of input dataframe while decreasing a date column by a month

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have data with 3 columns and around 50,000 rows. Below is the sample -

**ID    |    DATE(datetime64)    |    COUNT**
1    |    30-03-2021    |    45

I want each row of input data to be repeated by the value mentioned in COUNT column and while doing so, Each row should have DATE column decreased by a month as shown below:

**ID    |    DATE(datetime64)**
1    |    30-03-2021
1    |    28-02-2021
1    |    30-01-2021
......................
......................
1    |    30-07-2017

I have written a code to generate the above output but it is taking a lot of time(each row of input data is taking around 0.09199643135070801 seconds, and all 50000 records are taking about 35 minutes). Below is code I have written:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.relativedelta

data1 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ABD\\Desktop\\data1.csv",parse_dates=['DATE'])
start_time = time.time()
data2 =pd.DataFrame()
k=0
for i in range(len(data1)):
    for j in range(int(data1.loc[i,'COUNT']) ):
        if j==0:
            data2.loc[j+k,'ID'] = data1.loc[i,'ID']
            data2.loc[j+k,'NEW_DATE']=data1.loc[i,'DATE']
        else:
            data2.loc[j+k,'ID'] = data1.loc[i,'ID']
            data2.loc[j+k,'NEW_DATE']=data1.loc[i,'DATE'] - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=j)
    k=k+j+1
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

please tell me that there is more time efficient way of doing this. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be much quicker than using nested loops -

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Sample dataframe for testing
x = StringIO("""id,date,count
1,30-03-2021,4
2,28-02-2021,3
""")

df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=',')
print(df)


df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'id': row[0], 'date': pd.date_range(row[1], freq='-1M', periods=row[2])},
                              columns=['id', 'date']) for row in df.itertuples(name=None, index=False)],
                ignore_index=True)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   id       date
0   1 2021-03-31
1   1 2021-02-28
2   1 2021-01-31
3   1 2020-12-31
4   2 2021-02-28
5   2 2021-01-31
6   2 2020-12-31
```

Comment: wow, now entire 50k records are getting executed in less than 10 sec. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Your code is producing dates as month end dates, however, I want to keep the date same as input. See the example - 3rd line in expected output is 30-01-2021 but your code is producing 31-01-2021. Please help..